How can I include per user information into an installer file?
I vaguely remember that Spotify had a client, that when after downloading automatically logged me in as a user.
Ever since I was wondering how to achieve something like that. How to avoid login prompt if you started the download as a logged-in user.
Say I have windows executable .exe and I'd like to include a user id or some short lived token into it. How would I go about that? Is there a place inside the file that I can modify after compiling/publishing?
Bonus points if the technique is compatible with Windows UAC.
I guess nowadays best practice would be to have the installer open a webpage with a token and then see if the browser is logged in + ping back the installed version from the server?
